# Map a multi-level JSON object to NSManagedObject with Hyperolso Sync

Tags: json, swift, nsmanagedobject, nskeyedarchiver

I'm using the great Sync from HyperOslo to get a JSON object from an API:

JSON object:

```
{"user":
  {"name" : "damien",
   "email" : "myemail@gmail.com",
   "settings" : 
    { "notification" : "true",
      "secretKey" : "dzadd7z5a7dzd5azd"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my User object, subclassing NSManagedObject. with the property "settings" as a custom NSObject:

```
class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var email: String?
    @NSManaged var settings: Settings?
}
```

this looks impossible! (if something know an other third party framework?)

as [the doc](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync#attribute-types), the solution would be to use the Binary Data Type:

[image]

... but how build the getter of this property in my model?
(i know the getter below has any sense):

```
 @NSManaged var settings: Settings?{
  return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.settings];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework's builder advised me [a good alternative solution](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync/issues/124#issuecomment-152998587):

> Why not just create a new Core Data table for the new object?

1 - Add the entity in core data

[image]

2 - Create the NSManagedObject Subclass for the entity

```
class Setting: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var notification: Bool?
    @NSManaged var notification: String?
}
```

3 -  set `hyper.remoteKey = secretKey` in the user Info.

> If your JSON says "secret_key" Sync will map it to `secretKey` in Core
>   Data. But if your JSON says "secretKey" it doesn't know how to
>   transform it to `secretKey` because it only does automatic
>   transformations for `snake_case`. So if you wan to use `secretKey`
>   from your JSON you need to tell Sync this. You do it by adding
>   `hyper.remoteKey` (key) and `secretKey` as value in the user Info.

[image]

3 - create the "setting" relationship on User (don't forget to add the property in your model)

[image]